# Как понять что текст соответствует примеру

Tags: python, строки

Ну вот допустим, есть вот такая python строка: `some(shit("Hello, ", "world!"))`. И как понять, что она соответствует такому примеру: `some(shit("...", "..."))`. Вместо точек любые символы

Comment: Лучше поменяйте названия функций, у нас не институт благородных девиц, но это не профессионально :) Вы хотите проверить, что в этой строке, которая выглядит как функция в функции, в внутренней функции будет два параметра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сопоставления можно использовать регулярные выражения, пример:

```
some\(shit\("[^"]+", "[^"]+"\)\)
```

Как использовать (если вернулся объект `re.Match`, то шаблон соответствует, иначе `None`):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'some\(shit\("[^"]+", "[^"]+"\)\)')

print(pattern.search('some(shit("Hello, ", "world!"))'))
print(pattern.search('some(shit("...", "..."))'))
print(pattern.search('some(shit("...", "...", "..."))'))
print(pattern.search('some(shit("..."))'))
```

Результат:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 31), match='some(shit("Hello, ", "world!"))'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 24), match='some(shit("...", "..."))'>
None
None
```

---

**PS.**

Для получения `True`/`False` результат `re.search` оберните в `bool`:

```
print(bool(pattern.search('some(shit("..."))')))
```

Хотя можно и без этого в `if` помещать:

```
text = 'some(shit("..."))'
m = pattern.search(text)
if not m:
    # Логика если строка text не соответствует шаблону
```

Comment: спасибо, помог.

Comment: @kingley, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения предлагаю модуль **re**:

```
re.findall(pattern,string)
```

где: `pattern='some\(shit\([A-z]{1,5}\,\.*\)\)'`

В квадратных скобках указаны **символы, которые могут встречаться**, в фигурных их **количество**, обратный слеш нужен для **экранирования специальных знаков**

Comment: В `re` нет функции `find` :) Наверное, вы имели ввиду функцию `search`?

Comment: @gil9red виноват, имелось ввиду findall, сейчас исправлю